# Android - Recycling listview elements automatically?

Tags: android, listview, recycle

I created a listview that has a custom SimpleCursorAdapter. I want to place a header in the first element in the list. 8 views fit on the screen at a time. When I scroll down to the ninth view, the header of the 1st element appears. At least I believe that is what is happening. I removed a button above the listview allowing all of the elements to appear on screen and only the first element had the header.

I believe I am forcing a new view to be inflated each time. I have read up a bit on convertview and it appears to be something that you have to implement manually.

```
@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup parent) {

    final LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    int position = cursor.getPosition();
    View v;
    v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.roster_lv_row_entry_with_header, parent, false);      
    if(position > 0)
        v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.roster_lv_row_entry_no_header, parent, false);

    return v;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You shoul override the `(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)` method in your adapter class, and

1. assign the `convertView` parameter a
   new value (**if necessary**, but better just use it if it's the right type, and fill it with the proper data based on `yourListData.get(position)`, where `yourListData` is e.g. a `List<?>` extension.)
2. then return it.

Comment: I am having an issue with this. Where my app is loading an image in the background.. I have three items visible in the view and when I click on one of them. they repaint... the problem I am having is. that the listview is reusing the items that are still on the screen. or so it appears.

Comment: To avoid that, you should ALWAYS assign a new value to the convertView parameter, as it's in the 1. step. This way it won't cache and scrolling won't cause this side-effect.